# How implement a (swipeable) card in windows phone?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want to implement a swipeable card (left and right swipe) in a Windows Phone app. Is there any built in control for  making a card and moving it?

If there is no built in control for it then what is the best approach to build a card like below and animate the movement of it?

Note: I am not asking help about detecting and processing of the swipe gesture.

[image]

*figure showing the card*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about trying Carousel control though its available for Windows 10 for windows phone 8.1 you can refrence these two tutorials
[Tutorial 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mim/archive/2014/06/16/carousel-user-control-for-windows-8-1-and-windows-phone-8-1-manipulationdelta-arrangeoverride-and-animation.aspx)
[Tutorial 2](https://comentsys.wordpress.com/2015/04/24/windows-8-1-and-windows-phone-8-1-universal-application-carousel-control/)

Answer (score 1):

Carousel control is one good example of what you want to achieve.

Also , I think you can do such a thing by changing some Pivot & PivotItem styles.It could be more customized than Carousel control but you need to take more effort on that.